# Tomcat JSR356 Websocket - disable permessage-deflate compression

Tags: tomcat, websocket, compression

I'm, working on a Java servlet which runs on a Tomcat 8.0.18 server and uses the JSR356 websocket API to communicate with a browser.
By default Tomcat uses the "permessage-deflate" compression to compress the websocket messages in both directions. I want to use no websocket compression, how can it be turned off?
I have tried to use the compression="off" option in the file server.xml but that didn't change anything.
How can i turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add jvm option

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true
```

to catalina.bat (for windows) or catalina.sh (for unix like OS).

e.g. add this line at the beginning of catalina.sh

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true"
```

add this line at the beginning of catalina.bat

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true"
```