# Spring disable websocket compression -> Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket, spring-java-config

I have a spring boot app using websockets and stomp protocol. Since i moved to spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.3.0.M2 i have noticed an additional compresion header in the websocket handshake i.e.

Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate

It all works good for me, but i would like to have the opportunity to disable this header when i am running an development build. It seems that wireshark stomp plugging has a problem when this header is there. Thus the question how to i disable this header in my springsecurity java config for my  SecurityConfigDevelopmentProfile that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

As Spring Boot uses Tomcat, you could try disabling it as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30148633/1210793