# How Can I Disable Tomcat's permessage-deflate WebSocket Compression in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, websocket

I have a Spring Boot server that I would like to be able to communicate with websocket clients that are unable or unwilling to handle *permessage-deflate* compressed messages. I know from both of these similar questions on the topic (linked below) that I can add the VM argument `-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true` to disable Tomcat's default deflate compression.

- [Tomcat JSR356 Websocket - disable permessage-deflate compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894316/tomcat-jsr356-websocket-disable-permessage-deflate-compression)
- [Spring disable websocket compression -> Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804635/spring-disable-websocket-compression-sec-websocket-extensions-permessage-def)

However, I plan to make a program that will be distributed so others can run it, and having to force people to remember to always include a specific VM argument just to change a setting seems quite abrasive.

Is there some alternative way to disable Tomcat's websocket compression which doesn't require users to specify VM arguments at runtime, perhaps using Spring's Java configuration or a custom websocket handshake interceptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not only set properties using JVM arguments but also programmatically using `System.setProperty` like the following:

```java
System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS",String.valueOf(true));
```

If you export your project to a JAR-file using embedded tomcat, you can run it in your `main` before executing `SpringApplication.run`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS",String.valueOf(true));
    SpringApplication.run(YourApplicationClass.class,args);
}
```

If you package your application to a WAR file, you could try the following:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplicationClass extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS",String.valueOf(true));
        return application.sources(YourApplicationClass.class);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS` option was [removed](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/changelog.html) in Tomcat 10.1, so the answer by dan1st no longer works.

I managed to disable compression by removing the `permessage-deflate` from the request header by using a filter:

```
@Component
public class WebSocketHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        HttpServletRequest req = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public String getHeader(String name) {
                if ("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    return "";
                }
                return super.getHeader(name);
            }

            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {

                if ("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    return Collections.enumeration(Collections.emptyList());
                }
                return super.getHeaders(name);
            }
        };

        chain.doFilter(req, httpResponse);
    
    }
}
```

In my case it was enough to simply clear the value of the header. But since other WebSocket extensions may be requested by the client, it may be better to just remove the `permessage-deflate` from the header.