# Using PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE causing native memory leak in JETTY9.3.11

Tags: websocket, jetty, spring-websocket, jetty-9

We are using jetty version 9.3.11 Version jetty container for deploying our application

we are using tyrus client for connecting  client to websocket server that we have deployed.

when i connect using the following code:

```
WebSocket ws = null;
        try {

            ws = new WebSocketFactory().createSocket(server)
                    .addListener(new NotifierAdapter(userId, channel))
                    .addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE).connect();

        } catch (WebSocketException we) {
            connect(server, userId, channel);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return ws;
```

Around 8000 connections my machine was taking 40% Memory

But with the sight modification of code(removing deflate extension)

```
try {

            ws = new WebSocketFactory().createSocket(server)
                    .addListener(new NotifierAdapter(userId, channel))
                    .connect();

        } catch (WebSocketException we) {
            connect(server, userId, channel);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return ws;
```

Was able to connect to 15000 connections with only 15% Memory
Is there any leak with respective to deflaters even in latest version of Jetty server..

Is there any way to disable PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE in server side of jetty..
Also we are using spring websocket passing jettyrequestupgrade strategy

Spring config code is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebSocketConfigurer {


    private static final String NOTIFIER_ENDPOINT_URL = "/notificationHandler";

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(socketHandler(), NOTIFIER_ENDPOINT_URL).setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler socketHandler() {
        return new NotificationSocketHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultHandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {

        WebSocketPolicy policy = new WebSocketPolicy(WebSocketBehavior.SERVER);
        policy.setInputBufferSize(8192);
        policy.setIdleTimeout(600000);
        WebSocketServerFactory ws=new WebSocketServerFactory(policy);
        ws.getExtensionFactory().unregister("permessage-deflate");
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(ws));
    }

}
```

Although i did un register of permessage-deflate when i connect from browser in response header i can see that flag still enabled any other changes should be made in containter for this??

Or is there any problem with spring websocket configuration:

Also response header is as follows:

```
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:xbbUnu7pDWs9Q0st4T1LzsIfqao=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate
Upgrade:WebSocket
```

I think the bug below havent been resolved yet.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/293

Is there any workaround for this(Explicit configuration in jetty server to disable PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE in jetty server container or spring config for Jetty

After searching i couldnt find any solution on server container/code configuration with spring websocket was not working ..

As a workaround i wrote a interceptor which will  remove the parameter Sec Websocket entension from the header..so that server will send response without this extension

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the memory leak is a JVM bug with Deflate implementations in the JVM Classpath.

Setting up an ObjectPool just delays the inevitable, it will just slow down the memory leak.

If you have access to the `WebSocketServletFactory` then ...

```java
 factory.getExtensionFactory().unregister("permessage-deflate");
```

If you only have access via JSR-356, then implement a custom Configurator and strip the permessage-deflate extension out during the extension negotiation.

```java
public class StripExtensionsConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator
{
    @Override
    public List<Extension> getNegotiatedExtensions(List<Extension> installed, 
                                                   List<Extension> requested)
    {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already did unregister of that extension  WebSocketPolicy policy = new WebSocketPolicy(WebSocketBehavior.SERVER);
        policy.setInputBufferSize(8192);
        policy.setIdleTimeout(600000);
        WebSocketServerFactory ws=new WebSocketServerFactory(policy);
        ws.getExtensionFactory().unregister("permessage-deflate");
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler(new JettyRequestUpgradeStrategy(ws));

Comment: As we are doing unregister on websocketServerFactory it should disable the permessage deflate but with the above code specified also in the chrome browser am able to still see Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:xbbUnu7pDWs9Q0st4T1LzsIfqao=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate..can you please provide any workaround disabling in server container(jetty server configurations)

Comment: Also is there any thing similar to this in jetty server container(not application) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894316/tomcat-jsr356-websocket-disable-permessage-deflate-compression

Comment: As a workaround i wrote a interceptor which will remove the parameter Sec Websocket entension from the header..so that server will send response without this extension