# fiddler websocket unreadable code

Tags: websocket, fiddler

I am using fiddler(version v4.6.3.44034) to capture network traffic of websocket,but the content is unreadable code.Like this:

```
PayloadString:  �Vr���su��KLNN-(�-K-*��ϳ2�3�1�3���HM,*�MJM,�2413:20:24:4763 WSSession87.WebSocket'WebSocket #87'
MessageID:  Server.3
MessageType:    Text
PayloadString:  J�Vr���suqu��+K-*��ϳ2�3���HM,*�MJM,�2�1��+-N-��K�M�JL��̋�R P�13:20:28:5903 WSSession87.WebSocket'WebSocket #87'
MessageID:  Client.4
MessageType:    Text
PayloadString:  �V
u
v�tr���L�*.M�*HI-.��K,��_�_�������M,)-F613:20:28:5953 WSSession87.WebSocket'WebSocket #87'
MessageID:  Client.5
MessageType:    Text
PayloadString:  t�?o�1ƿ��X��q��ЁnL�c�m+�G՞XP�;>�"e���?���p{����W�����*_��a���t���tw�?/�ߏ�Ա��}�>���x^�L�w�ç�x�է�����p:�2�z֌}N�WΛ�o�2y�   ��m0�TXM��u�E�����з2��u��<P��>H�V�С��tp_�eR��z�*�\�*Ў]��z��Z��a�b�J,�
�����w��}�m��
W�fPԦb!-Ev��גR�%�Z�4��l�c`�ov�z��$� �6���x#��RAmmiU�!%
X�y�滠�fT`
```

How to make it right? I searching from google,no one encount the problem.

Comment: Can you send me a SAZ file? Is there some reason to believe that the target is using string payloads and not some compressed format?

Comment: I don't know much about Fiddler. this looks like binary data to me. Check the OpCode or the subprotocol of the Websocket Frame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Fiddler (in my case v4.6.20171.7553) is not uncompressing the websocket traffic.  As a workaround, disable websocket compression on the server side.  In my case, I was using tomcat and added this jvm option:

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.websocket.DISABLE_BUILTIN_EXTENSIONS=true
```

Note that disabling http compression in server.xml did not work for me.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894316/tomcat-jsr356-websocket-disable-permessage-deflate-compression) for additional information.